# prediction from incomplete observations

Tags: classification, prediction, missing-data

Suppose I have a linear model predicting class-membership from a set of predictors. Now, I am going to classify a new observation which has, however, some predictor values missing. How can I deal with such situation? I know there are methods for imputing the missing values but I would like to avoid this and to use only measurements that were really made.

Comment: Do you know which predictors will be missing?

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to deal with this situation without imputation would be to refit the model without the missing predictors.